# How do i make it so it accepts both command line args

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner, string-conversion

I seem to be messing something up as  when i run the code it fails out at my first if statement with the output being "must have 2 cmd line args".

Im trying to figure out where I'm messing up and unfortunately I'm at a desktop that wont allow me to use netbeans or eclipse to try and remedy this issue. basically i want it to accept both commandline args when i enter them after I get my prompt on what my X and Y values will be.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GenerationX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" What numbers would you like to enter? Remember you need an 'X' and a 'Y' input: ");
        int i;
        int num = 0;
        String str = " ";
        int j = input.nextInt();
        int k = input.nextInt();

        if(args.length < 2) { //exits if less than two args entered
            System.out.println("must have two cmd line args");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            Random random = new Random();
            int repeat = validateArg(args[0]);
            int range = validateArg(args[1]);
            for(int count = 0; count < repeat; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%s ", random.nextInt(range));
            //Process each character of the string;
                while( j < str.length() && k < str.length()) {
                    num *= 10;
                    num += str.charAt(j++) - '0'; //Minus the ASCII code of '0' to get the value of the charAt(i++).
                    num += str.charAt(k++) - '0';
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
    static int validateArg(String arg) {
        int result = 0;

        try { //tries to parse first arg into variable
            result = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("arg bad. Prog exiting.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if(result <= 0) {
            System.out.println("arg must be positive");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if i need the int k method for the scanner input but it was my failed attempt to get the code to accept both args in order to bypass the first if statement, also I want to leave this in in order to add corrective action to this.

Comment: The command line arguments come from how you execute the application. Eg: `java GenerationX arg1 arg2`  How are you executing the application?

Comment: Unfortunately Im having to use an online compiler browxy and do not have access to use my command line at work, but in your case I understand what you're saying. I wanted to be able to prompt the user to input the two arguments then have the code run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

You need to create a new array and add j and k to the array like this:

```
Integer[] array = {null, null};
array[0] = j;
array[1] = k;
```

Then your if statement should check to see if either value is null like this:

```
if (array[0] == null || array[1] == null){
    //insert code to do stuff here
}
```

`args` is actually an array made from what is inputted in the command line when the program is first run. So to add values to args, the user would have to open a command line and execute

`java [ClassName] [arg0] [arg1] ...`

Comment: Im trying to do what you suggested and created a new array and added it after my initial string method and rewrote my first if statement to what you suggested but i then get the error cannot find symbols variables j and k and incomparable types int and null, so I'm assuming i took your advice and implemented it incorrectly

Comment: Okay, I am seeing the problem. I'm actually a little off. You want to use Integer objects instead of primitive ints. I am editing my answer to reflect that. Also you would want to create the array and add them after the line: `int k = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Okay so it got past the whole issue thanks to your input which is why i submitted it as the answer, but now when i run the program it works, then I input 2 random values for example 24 15 and i get an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at GenerationX.main(GenerationX.java:21)" error

Comment: I am assuming that line 21 is the line `int repeat = validateArg(args[0]);` change `args` to `array`  If not, which line is 21?

Comment: that is correct for your line 21 ? and I want to start off by saying you're a life saver, I've been working on this all day and with no tool to help, your comments make a huge difference. I changed the args to array and got a whole new set of errors. Compilation Errors Detected

Line: 20, method validateArg in class GenerationX cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String, found: java.lang.Integer
  reason: actual argument java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion. Same for line 21

Comment: Change your method header for the method validateArg() to accept an Integer `static int validateArg(Integer arg){` then you wont have any need for the `try-catch` or the `Integer.parseInt(` in the method.

Comment: alright it finally works, except it doesnt anything after i input my two arguments and if i leave the if statement result<=0 it returns args must be positive im not sure if this is just because im using an online compiler or if im just not getting it but I do want to say thank you regardless

Comment: doesn't display anything*

Comment: @3monkeys1gorilla Glad I could be some help. Since `args` held Strings and `array` now holds Integers, you will need to watch out for other parts of the program that need to be changed to complement this change.

Comment: Awesome will do, now i just need to find out how to change this properly, le sigh lol

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out with the help of @ Jonah Haney and another few hours of staring at it before a Java guru pointed out that I just needed to change a word.

heres the working code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomXY {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" What numbers would you like to enter? Remember you need an 'X' and a 'Y' input: ");
        int num = 0;
        String str = " ";
        int i = input.nextInt();
        int j = input.nextInt();
        Integer[] array = {null, null};
        array[0] = i;
        array[1] = j;

        if(array[0] == null || array[1] == null) { //exits if less than two args entered
            System.out.println("must have 2 command line arguments");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            Random random = new Random();
            int repeat = validateArg(array[0]);
            int range = validateArg(array[1]);
            for(int count = 0; count < repeat; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%s ", random.nextInt(range));
            //Process each character of the string;
                while( i < str.length() && j < str.length()) {
                    num *= 10;
                    num += str.charAt(i++) - '0'; //Minus the ASCII code of '0' to get the value of the charAt(i++).
                    num += str.charAt(j++) - '0';
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
    private static int validateArg(Integer arg) {
        if(arg <= 0) {
            System.out.println("arguments must be positive");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return arg;
    }
}
```